# Using DLL in debug or release mode?

Tags: c++, sqlite, dll, visual-c++-2012

I downloaded a precompiled SQLite DLL from http://www.sqlite.org at this link [sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3080600.zip](http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3080600.zip).

Can I use the same DLL both in Debug and Release mode? What would be the difference and how is it possible? I'm using Visual C++ 2012 Compiler.

Comment: Yes you can. There would be no difference. It's possible because its authors carefully designed it this way.

Comment: So, if I compile their .dll using their source code then I guess I shouldn't just mix the release mode dll with debug mode and vice-versa but still it is possible to mix and it compiles.

Comment: I failed to parse this sentence. I do not understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: If I compile their .dll using their source code from http://sqlite.org and produce two DLLs for debug and release mode then why is it still possible to use them interchangeably i.e. using release .dll in debug mode which still compiles. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: Yes you are. Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Because I thought I should only use Debug .dll to compile in debug mode and Release .dll to compile in release mode. Suppose, If I don't want to debug the functions that comes with .dll then it is perfectly fine to use just release dll in debug mode, right?

Comment: Yes, if the DLL in question was carefully designed to avoid sharing CRT resources with the caller. SQLite was.

Comment: But it is not possible to step into any of functions used by their pre-compiled .dll which compiles in debug and release mode. So, I guess I cannot say that it fully supports debugging.

Comment: Their pre-built DLL was built in release mode. Also, they don't ship .pdb file - that's the file that makes it possible for the debugger to line up machine assembly and the source code. If you want to step through SQLite source code, build said source code yourself.

Comment: In that case I could just build my own .DLL in release mode with their source code using /MD switch in compiler instead of using their pre-built DLL. Their .dll links with "MSVCRT.DLL" runtime while the one that I built uses newer version "MSVCR110.DLL" of runtime. Wouldn't it be problem if one .dll uses "MSVCRT.DLL" while the rest of others use "MVCR110.DLL"?

Comment: Don't you have empiric evidence answering your question? Again, two modules using different CRT flavors doesn't cause problems as long as the interface between them doesn't require them to share CRT resources (e.g. one module doesn't need to deallocate memory allocated by the other).

Answer (score 1):

For the DLL internals to be visible in debug mode, it has to be compiled in debug mode. Otherwise, no debug info will be available (e.g. watch variables, step into, etc.). On the other hand, a DLL compiled in debug mode shouldn't be used for release since it is slower and contains unnecessary code. I am not sure if the existence of the debug functions constitute a security risk, but having additional hooks in your DLL in a production environment doesn't sound safe.

Hope that helps!