# Force osg to use the release version of a plugin dll in the debug build

Tags: c++, dll, openscenegraph

I am writing a program using OSG and I would like to step through it to see how stuff works, change a few lines and debug again. However every time I need to load a file using osgDB plugin for openflight. The debug version of the plugin works quite slow. I have no intention of debugging the plugin itself, so I figured I might as well use the release dll. I read that I can do this as long as there are no memory allocation  in program and freeing in dll or visa versa and if the dll was designed to avoid problems that might occur with release/debug mixing. I'm not sure if `osgdb_openflight.dll` was designed like that.

**My question:** can I use the release plugin dll in my debug build, and how can I make my program use it?

**UPD:** I achieved my goal following the @XenonofArcticus's advice.

Some additional thoughts on the topic for the sake of better understanding:
I also tried to simply rename the release dll, so it would get loaded in the debug build. (I thought this would work, because I usually use release dlls in debug builds - Windows's, SQL's and other 3rd party dlls, that do not come with debug info. Also see Igor Tandetnik's comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829619/using-dll-in-debug-or-release-mode)).  It did and the program didn't crash, however it also didn't load the file. Apparently this particular dll wasn't designed to be used in debug builds. Any other explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you're going to achieve what you want trying to mix debug and release. However, perhaps it would work to build a release with debug symbols target? This can allow you to do SOME debugging, but it's still a release build and behaves like one.

Comment: I updated the question, trying to understand the topic better, care to comment? )